# Cannot install devtools package in R 3.5.3

Tags: r, devtools

I installed "devtools" package in R. However, I got error message when trying to open it with # library (devtools) #.

I have R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11). I read a previous post with the same error message as I got which was solved by installing curl. I tried # install.packages(c('devtools','curl')) #, but got the same error message when running # library (devtools) #. The previous post mentioned choosing older version of compiling, but I didn't get any options during installing of devtools and curl. And I have tried to remove both packages and installed again and it didn't work.

```
> install.packages("devtools")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/devtools_2.0.2.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 377464 bytes (368 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 368 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/yh/v0kgt64n5k1_2vl7ff419r680000gp/T//Rtmpr5jn5k/downloaded_packages


> library (devtools)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘fs’
```

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages("fs")`?

Comment: Thank you, that works! I didn't think about that "fs" is a real package. After installing "fs", devtools works now for me.